# PHP photo gallery

Tags: php

I'm trying to build a social networking site for a class project in php and i'm slightly confused on how to build the photo gallery. Where i'm getting confused is how I should be storing the pictures and the database structure for storing the pictures. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to approach that but I will give you here the most straightforward way. The goal is for you to understand the basic steps.

```
1- You should create a folder called 'images' under your root folder.
2- You upload the file to this folder. This tutorial shows you how : 
   http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp
   Note: you will want to save the file under a name of your choice. Be careful in chosing a unique name to avoid overwriting other files in the folder.
3- On the database side, you will just need to insert the PATH or URL of the file on your server.
4- In your view, you would insert the image this way : 
   <img src="<?php echo $image_path; ?>" alt="">
```

I hope you get the idea. Good luck!!!